# Solving for $I- A$ based on LU factorization of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Suppose I have the LU factorization for a given matrix $A$ ($A$ is *not* symmetric positive definite), then is there a faster way to solve for $x$ in the following equation, as compared to doing LU all over again?

$$
(I - A)x = b
$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: $I-A$ need not be invertible to start with

Comment: @user251257 I am sorry, can you please elaborate.

Comment: If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $I-A$ is not invertible and the system $(I-A) x = b$ has no solution. That doesn't say that it isn't possible to solve $(I-A) x= b$ using a $LU$ factorization of $A$, it is just likely not trivial...